# How do I force the php function ssh2_sftp() to crash or timeout instead of hanging?

Tags: php, ssh, sftp, ssh2-sftp

I am trying to connect to ftp with the following code in php

```
$connection = ssh2_connect($host, $port);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, $user, $password);
$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);
```

However, instead of triggering an error, the script just hangs.
When I try connecting via the linux command line, I get the error

```
Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: <login date> from <my ip>
Could not chdir to home directory /xxx/xxx/./xxx/xxxx/xxx: No such file or directory
Connection to <my ip> closed.
```

How do I get the script to trigger an error (preferably something more specific about what happened) instead of hanging?

Comment: I generally don't like to just say "try this library", but when it comes to SSH, SFTP or anything related to certificates, I have found that using the [phpseclib](https://phpseclib.com/docs/sftp) has saved me so many headaches, and has really good [debugging support](https://phpseclib.com/docs/diagnosis)

Comment: "hanging" is usually waiting for the timeout